# How to find maximum sum in a 2D matrix

Tags: matrix, sum

I want to find the maximum sum in a 2D matrix such that:

```
You can pick only 1 element from each row
You cannot pick a column that has been picked before.
```

Example:

```
matrix = [ [12, 1, 1, 1], [13, 10, 1, 1], [40, 1, 1, 12] ]
```

Solution:

```
We pick 12 from 1st row
```

Now we cannot `pick 13 from 2nd row` as the column has already been used. Therefore, `will pick 10 in 2nd row`.
We can either `pick 1 or 12 from 3rd row` as 1st and `2nd columns have already been used`. `We will pick 12 in 3rd row`

So:

```
sum = 12 + 10 + 12 = 34
```

This is not the maximum answer.

```
Max. answer = 1 + 10 + 40 = 51.
```

Can we solve this using Hungarian algorithm? Are there any better options? Kindly help.

Note: This is not a problem of any ongoing contestN

I found that the Hungarian algorithm will probably work, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Are any other options?